# Laravel call different controller for same resource route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I made a resource controller and route in my api.php. Now I want to create a new route like in Route 2. The issue is when I hit the second route it shows me no resource found error because it's called my test. show method. I want to use both routes is there any solution for that?

```
Route 1 => Route::resource('test', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\v1\MyController');
Route 2 => Route::get('test/greetings', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\v1\MyController@greetingsData');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line orders. Laravel use first line from top that is appropriate candidate.

```
Route 1 => Route::get('test/greetings', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\v1\MyController@greetingsData');
Route 2 => Route::resource('test', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\v1\MyController');
```

Answer (score 1):

put the new sub route in the top/above of the resource. should be like:

```
Route::get('test/greetings', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\v1\MyController@greetingsData');
Route::resource('test', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\v1\MyController');
```